# Solr connection refused error after java update on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, macos, solr, sunspot-rails

I recently updated Java for Mac OS X 10.7-Update 1. After that I recognized that in my local development application under Rails 3.0.10 with sunspot/solr the solr-server starts correctly

```
0:03.80 /usr/bin/java -Dsolr.data.dir=/var/folders/j0/h6j1w2px233bb_g2461l8pnr0000gn/T -Dsolr.solr.home=/Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/sunspot-a32d14da2650/sunspot_solr/solr/solr -jar start.jar
```

But if I send a fully functional search request I get a connection refused error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))
```

One of my collegues recently updated its installation of OS X Snow Leopard with the Java Update for OS X 10.6-Update 6 and is getting the same error, so we determined the Java Update as a possible reason, since solr is Java based.

I am using on Rails 3.0.10 following gems:

```
gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => 'https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot'
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git'
```

Can someone help me with this problem or confirm its appearence after updating Java on OS X?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to ask the guys at serverfault.com they are better suited for installation issues.

Answer (score 0):

We could fix it with the help of one of the contributors from sunspot rails and returned to a release candidate gem verioned before the last update.

```
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git', :ref => '79175ea'
gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => 'https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot', :ref => '79175ea'
```

This fixed the issue for us be we are pretty sure that it was caused by the Mac OS Java update.

Comment: since version update to 1.3.0 of sunspot-rails and sunspot-solr this issue affects problem not longer.